Perform determinations within a data partition
I have a dataset as below from which I would like to draw some inferences.



Id
Nbr
Dt
Status
Cont1Sta1
DateLagInDays
Recurrence




1
2
2023-10-1
1





1
2
2023-11-2
0





1
2
2023-12-13
0





1
3
2023-10-1
0





1
3
2023-11-2
0





1
3
2023-12-13
1





1
9
2023-11-1
0





1
9
2023-12-1
1





1
9
2024-1-1
0






I have already created a SQL server data partition based on ID, number, and ordered by dt in ascending order.
The inferences needed are:

For the chosen partition are there any instances with status = 1.
If #1 is true, the date difference between the earliest of the instances where status=0 until the row has status=1.


Within the partition, are there any new rows disregarding status value after there is at least one row with status=1?

Is this possible using partition basic logic? I did try using lag and lead within the partition, but it would not yield a good result.
Any suggestion to write a good concise code will be helpful.
While I tried few other things, I have below clean code that I am using so far. I would like to have the columns Cont1Sta1, DateLagInDays, Recurrence be filled per partition after transformation, in the first instance row.
declare @t table
(
    id int,
    nbr int,
    dt date,
    status smallint,
    Cont1Sta1 bit,--if the chosen partition has atleast one status=1
    DateLagInDays int,--date diff in days from earliest record within partition to when status=1
    Recurrence bit --does partition has atleast one new row after one possible row that has status=1
)
insert into @t(id,nbr,dt,status) select 1,9,'2023-11-1',0
insert into @t(id,nbr,dt,status) select 1,9,'2023-12-1',1
insert into @t(id,nbr,dt,status) select 1,9,'2024-1-1',0
insert into @t(id,nbr,dt,status) select 1,2,'2023-10-1',1
insert into @t(id,nbr,dt,status) select 1,2,'2023-11-2',0
insert into @t(id,nbr,dt,status) select 1,2,'2023-12-13',0
insert into @t(id,nbr,dt,status) select 1,3,'2023-10-1',0
insert into @t(id,nbr,dt,status) select 1,3,'2023-11-2',0
insert into @t(id,nbr,dt,status) select 1,3,'2023-12-13',1;

select 
    id, nbr, dt,status,
    rank() over (partition by id, nbr, status order by id, nbr, dt asc, status desc) rownbr
from 
    @t
order by 
    id, nbr, dt asc, status desc;

Here is the desired tabular result:



Id
Nbr
Dt
Status
Cont1Sta1
DateLagInDays
Recurrence




1
2
2023-10-1
0
1
32
1


1
2
2023-11-2
1
0
0
0


1
2
2023-12-13
0
0
0
0


1
3
2023-10-1
0
1
73
0


1
3
2023-11-2
0
0
0
0


1
3
2023-12-13
1
0
0
0


1
9
2023-11-1
1
1
0
1


1
9
2023-12-1
0
0
0
0


1
9
2024-1-1
0
0
0
0




Why do DateLagInDays and Recurrence only have values in the first row in the partition, by you requirement it seems you should have the same value in the whole partition? Also your results don't match your sample DDL.

Your DDL has row 4 with Status=1, it looks like it should be row 5 instead. And the reverse for rows 7 & 8. Anyway, do you want something like this https://dbfiddle.uk/82uBvdXh

I see what you mean, I have fixed the first table. I also agree that your answer is impeccable, thank you!

After some clarification, it seems you only want the first row per group. You can use row-numbering for that.
The rest of your calculations can be done with conditional aggregation using window functions.
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
      t.id,
      t.nbr,
      t.dt,
      t.status,
      COUNT(CASE WHEN t.status = 1 THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY t.ID, t.nbr) AS Cont1Sta1,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.ID, t.nbr ORDER BY t.dt) AS rn,
      DATEDIFF(day, t.dt, MIN(CASE WHEN t.status = 1 THEN t.dt END) OVER (PARTITION BY t.ID, t.nbr)) AS DateLagInDays,
      IIF(
          MAX(t.dt) OVER (PARTITION BY t.ID, t.nbr) >
          MIN(CASE WHEN t.status = 1 THEN t.dt END) OVER (PARTITION BY t.ID, t.nbr),
        1, 0) AS Recurrence
    FROM @t t
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;

db<>fiddle

This solution is very efficient and concise, I must say!

Comments explaining the logic are embedded in the query.
with cte as (
    select id, nbr, dt, status
        -- get a row number so we can only show the calculated data once per partition
        , row_number() over (partition by id, nbr order by id, nbr, dt asc, status desc) rn
        -- Determine whether status 1 exists within the partition
        , max(status) over (partition by id, nbr) partition_status
        -- Get the first date where Status = 1
        , min(case when Status = 1 then dt else null end) over (partition by id, nbr) partition_dt1
        -- Get the last date where Status = 1
        -- Only required if there is the possibility of more than one Status = 1 row in a partition
        , max(case when Status = 1 then dt else null end) over (partition by id, nbr) partition_dt2
    from @t
)
select id, nbr, dt, status
    -- On the first row of each partition show whether a status = 1 exists
    , case when rn = 1 then partition_status else 0 end Cont1Sta1
    -- On the first row of each partition show the date lag in days
    , case when rn = 1 then datediff(day, dt, coalesce(partition_dt1, dt)) else 0 end DateLagInDays
    -- On the first row of each partition show whether any records exist after the last Status = 1
    , case when rn = 1 and exists (select 1 from cte c2 where c2.id = c1.id and c2.nbr = c1.nbr and c2.dt > c1.partition_dt2) then 1 else 0 end Recurrence
from cte c1
order by id, nbr, dt asc, status desc;

Returns as requested:



id
nbr
dt
status
Cont1Sta1
DateLagInDays
Recurrence




1
2
2023-10-01
1
1
0
1


1
2
2023-11-02
0
0
0
0


1
2
2023-12-13
0
0
0
0


1
3
2023-10-01
0
1
73
0


1
3
2023-11-02
0
0
0
0


1
3
2023-12-13
1
0
0
0


1
9
2023-11-01
0
1
30
1


1
9
2023-12-01
1
0
0
0


1
9
2024-01-01
0
0
0
0



DBFiddle

Wow, this is an absolutely beautiful solution! Thank you so much for both helping me get the question right as well as the solution.
